# How to remove all duplicated strings from a Java List?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, set

For a given list, say `[ "a", "a", "b", "c", "c" ]` I need `[ "b" ]` (*only non duplicated elements*) as output. Note that this is different from using the `Set` interface for the job...

I wrote the following code to do this in Java:

```
void unique(List<String> list) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    List<String> dup = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (String e : list) {
        i = list.indexOf(e);
        j = list.lastIndexOf(e);

        if (i != j && !dup.contains(e)) {
            dup.add(e);
        }
    }

    list.removeAll(dup);
}
```

It works... but for a list of size 85320, ends after several minutes!

Comment: I could be a nice algorithmic problem. Are the values of the list somehow limited (for example only ascii chars)?

Comment: If a element occur more than 1, then all of its occurrences must be removed from the list.

Comment: Why is Set not allowed?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not convinced that OP is saying Set isn't allowed - only that the desired output isn't simply what you'd get from `new HashSet<>(list)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner got the point. Exactly!

Comment: @AndyTurner Then the question title was badly worded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You best performance is with set:

```
    String[] xs = { "a", "a", "b", "c", "c" };

    Set<String> singles = new TreeSet<>();
    Set<String> multiples = new TreeSet<>();

    for (String x : xs) {
        if(!multiples.contains(x)){
            if(singles.contains(x)){
                singles.remove(x);
                multiples.add(x);
            }else{
                singles.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a single pass and insert , remove and contains are log(n).

Comment: what about LinkedHashSet?

Comment: Maybe even faster, depending on how good is the hash, possibly needing more memory.

Comment: I'm using native (Java) Strings for each data item. So, I hope it has a very good hash.

Comment: There is "not using Set" in the question's title. `TreeSet` is a `Set`...

Comment: Note: you can use `if (singles.remove(x))` instead of calling contains and then remove.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right, I just don't use sets often, to be sincere I never use them, because every time I use a set I then have to refactor to use a map instead.

Comment: TreeSet keeps the elements ordered which makes it slower than e.g. HashSet.

Comment: Hash set needs rehashing, I really don't know if there's truly an absolute winner (performance wise), I think that much depends on how many collisions you have.

Answer (score 5):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
return list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @nazar_art missing bracket (and missing .stream()). Now added.

Comment: The reason why I'm not a great fan of java streams (I still use them when they provide simpler solutions) is that they fail to achieve both conciseness and clarity, in scala the same stament would be `list groupBy identity collect {case(k,_+:Nil) => k}`

Comment: @minus I believe the culprit is the `.collect(...)` part.  The whole Collectors scenario is quite complex, perhaps more than needed, and it doesn't help that Java only allows for a single return value.

Comment: I completely agree, collectors are difficult to use (hard to remember also) and switching back and forth from streams to collection add a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `streams` to achieve this in simpler steps as shown below with inline comments:

```
//Find out unique elements first
List<String> unique = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

//List to collect output list
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

//Iterate over each unique element
for(String element : unique) {

    //if element found only ONCE add to output list
    if(list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(element)).count() == 1) {
        output.add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: It takes around 50-55 seconds in my PC

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Map. do the following

```
1. Create a map of following type Map<String, Integer>
2. for all elements
       check if the string is in hashmap
             if yes then increment the value of that map entry by 1
       else add <current element , 1>
3. now your output are those entries of the Map whose values are 1.
```

Comment: But he does not want to use a Set or similar datastructure

Comment: @prasanth I'm not sure that's what OP is saying about "not Set" - I interpret it as saying it's not simply doing what a set would do, in that the desired output is not simply the distinct values.

Comment: The title says "not using Set". That is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can sort the list, about the most efficient way to do this is to use a `ListIterator` to iterate over runs of adjacent elements:

```
List<String> dup = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list);
ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  String first = it.next();

  // Count the number of elements equal to first.
  int cnt = 1;
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    String next = it.next();
    if (!first.equals(next)) {
        it.previous();
        break;
    }
    ++cnt;
  }

  // If there are more than 1 elements between i and start
  // it's duplicated. Otherwise, it's a singleton, so add it
  // to the output.
  if (cnt == 1) {
    dup.add(first);
  }
}

return dup;
```

`ListIterator` is more efficient for lists which don't support random access, like `LinkedList`, than using index-based access.